# Is there any reasonable non-regular Gödel numbering of the language of arithmetic?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, peano-arithmetic

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the language of arithmetic given as follows:

- $x::= {\sf v} \mid x'$
- $t ::= x \mid 0 \mid {\sf S}t \mid (t+t) \mid (t\times t)$
- $A ::= \bot \mid \top \mid t=t \mid \neg A \mid (A \wedge A) \mid (A \vee A) \mid (A \to A) \mid \forall x\,A \mid \exists x\, A$

**Definition.** Let $\xi$ be a numbering of $\mathcal{L}$. We call $\xi$ *regular* if for all closed $\mathcal{L}$-terms $u,t$ we have

- $\xi(\mathsf{S}t) > \xi(t) + 1$;
- $\xi((t+u)) > \xi(t) + \xi(u)$;
- $\xi((t \times u)) > \xi(t) \cdot \xi(u)$.

We may reformulate the definition of regularity for alternative *reasonable* notation systems, such as Polish notation, etc.

**Question.** Is there any *reasonable* numbering of $\mathcal{L}$ which is not regular?

The idea is to find such a numbering with a minimum of hacking. It should, as it were, be a numbering someone could come up with without our question in mind. It would be already interesting to know whether this holds for the sub-language of $\mathcal{L}$ which only contains $0$, $\mathsf{S}$ and $\times$.

This question appeared while writing a paper with Albert Visser on Gödel numberings which satisfy the Strong Diagonal Lemma for $\mathcal{L}$ (i.e., without extra function symbols). Clearly, the constraint of regularity (plus monotonicity) rules out such numberings and is satisfied by all standard numberings we are aware of. We wonder whether there are any natural candidates which do not satisfy this constraint?

Comment: What additional restrictions are you placing on your numbering? Why can't you just swap + and ×?

Comment: Thank you for these questions. Regrettably, we don't have precise sufficient conditions for a numbering to be natural or reasonable. But surely every such numbering should be injective, effective and monotonic (the code of an expression is larger than the codes of its sub-expressions).

Comment: To see that these three conditions are not sufficient, consider the length-first ordering $\lambda$ of $\mathcal{L}$'s alphabet. Now, define the code of an expression $e$ of $\mathcal{L}$ to be $\xi(e) := \lambda(e) + k$, for some fixed $k$. $\xi$ is injective, effective and monotonic. If we choose $k$ sufficiently large, $\xi$ is not regular. But $\xi$ is not natural or reasonable in the sense we have in mind, since it is clearly cooked up specifically with our question in mind.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question: The constraint of regularity resorts to the intended interpretation of the symbols $\mathsf{S}$, $\times$ and $+$. That being said, for every standard numbering $\xi$ I can think of right now, we also have that $\xi(t) \cdot \xi(u) < \xi((t + u))$. Did you have a specific counter-example based on swapping in mind?

Comment: I think the condition $\xi((t\times u))>\xi(t)\xi(u)$ would be violated for various kinds of dag (directed acyclic graph) based representations of formulas/terms. For any $t$ the dag encoding $t\times t$ is the dag encoding $t$ with one additional vertice. Note that if you treat natural numbers as bit-strings, then multiplication of natural numbers has the same order of growth as concatenation of bit-strings. But it is fairly clear that for "reasonable" encodings of dags by binary strings an addition of one vertice shouldn't double the length of the code, for large enough dags.

Comment: I dislike the question because you will reject the following answer, which however happens in practice millions of times every day: take your Gödel number and run the ZIP compression algorithm on it.

Answer (score 4):

For the language which contains only $0$, $\mathsf{S}$ and $\times$, one reasonable way to describe a term is by the sequence of strings of esses. E.g.
\begin{align}
\mathsf{S}0 &\text{ is “one set of one ess"}\\
\mathsf{SS}0\times \mathsf{S}0 &\text{ is “one set of two esses and one set of one ess"}\\
\mathsf{SS}0\times\mathsf{S}0\times \mathsf{S}0 &\text{ is “one set of two esses and two sets of one ess"}\\
\end{align}

Rendering those English-language descriptions as numbers in base 26 gives a numbering scheme $\xi$ for the language. But the example above shows that the scheme is not regular because
$$\xi(\mathsf{SS}0\times\mathsf{S}0\times \mathsf{S}0) <
\xi(\mathsf{SS}0\times \mathsf{S}0)
\cdot \xi(\mathsf{S}0)$$

A similar scheme for $\mathcal{L}$ could also be irregular.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** I have read Fedor Pakhomov's comment above and his comment contains all points essential in my answer but in a much compressed form. Indeed, substitutions may be seen as forming a DAG, and Fedor also uses an argument from the rate of growth of iterated squaring vs. the linear length of a term in a DAG-like form. So my answer is rather an elaboration on Fedor's comment. **End of edit**

Let me provide an example of such a non-regular coding which I believe is not completely ``out of the blue''. The inspiration for it comes from boolean circuits. There, a circuit is called a formula if all its internal nodes have out-degree at most one. This means that we cannot use a function computed by a node more than once. Such a circuit easily translates into a boolean formula of a similar size. 
I'll do the opposite.

Imagine that while making our Gödel coding we want to be space efficient. So, while computing $\xi(t)$, we want to code efficiently subterms which appear more than once in a term $t$. 
This corresponds to a situation when we allow arbitrary circuits to code our terms and formulas.

Assume that we want to code a term $t$ which is of the form $t'(s\backslash x)$, where $x$ occurs in $t'$ more than once and $x$ does not occur in $t$. Then, we may represent $t$ as a sequence 
$(s \rightarrow x)(t')$. Of course, while writing down $t'$ and $s$ we use the same trick recursively. Finally, the obtained sequence of symbols can be coded by any efficient coding 
of sequences of bits. Let $\xi$ be such a coding. The point is that such a method may decrease the length (and the size) of codes for terms with lots of regularities.

A coding as above is not regular. Let me provide an example. I take a sequence of terms. The term $t_0=2$ and  $t_{i+1}=(t_i*t_i)$. The length of the term $t_i$ is $O(2^{i})$ and its the value is $2^{2^{i}}$. On the other hand, the length 
of a sequence describing $t_i$ with substitutions is $O(i\log_2(i))$ (the $\log_2(i)$ factor
comes from the lengths of new variables in the sequence of substitutions). Such a sequence may look like this: 
$$
(2\rightarrow x_0)(x_0 * x_0\rightarrow x_1)(x_1*x_1\rightarrow x_2)\dots 
          (x_{i-2}*x_{i-2}\rightarrow x_{i-1})(x_{i-1}*x_{i-1}).
$$
As the length of this sequence is $O(i\log_2(i))$, 
the Gödel number for this sequence, $\xi(t_i)$,  is of order $2^{O(i\log_2(i))}$.

Let $\text{val}(t)$ be the value of a term $t$.
Now, let us assume that $2<\xi(2)$ and let us take $i$ big enough. I claim that it is impossible
that $\forall j<i (\xi(t_j)*\xi(t_j)< \xi(t_{j+1}))$. It this would be the case,
then for all $j\leq i$ the value of $t_j$ would be less then $\xi(t_j)$.
But this is impossible, as the value of $t_i$ is $2^{O(2^i)}$ while $\xi(t_i)$ 
is $2^{O(i\log_2(i))}$.

PS. 
The above coding allows to reconstruct $t$ from $\xi(t)$. But $\xi(t)$ depends on the choice
of terms $s$ that we substitute. If one would like to make $\xi(t)$ unique, then one should 
fix this choice. E.g. one could always choose the longest term $s$ which occurs more than once
in $t$ and the leftmost one if such $s$ is not unique.

PPS.
If we have totality of $\exp$ then the function computing a value of a term from its code
is total. However, in models of weak arithmetics (without $\exp$) we may have codes of terms
for which ''values'' would be "outside" a model.

Comment: You’ve been a member for 6 years and 5 months, so I’m honored to give you your first upvote!

Comment: Thank you, it's nice. The topic is one of my favourite so I could not resist to provide an example.